# Error in UITableView Section Header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableviewsectionheader

I have an ios app written in swift. I am trying to make an input form using [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka). So first I copied its [example code](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Example/Example/ViewController.swift#L105) into my `FormViewController`. The code is exactly same of `RowsExampleViewController` in the example code. The resultant output is following:

[image: screencast]

The expected output (as shown on github page of Eureka) was:

[image: original]

As you can see that the Section Headers are floating for some reason and not properly formatted.

Whats is the possible problem I should look at? Please let me know which section of code should I paste. The ViewController code is exactly same as that of example.

Also, I faced similar [problem](https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms/issues/82) while using [SwiftForms](https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms). I think there might be some connection.

Comment: It looks like it's mixing two styles of UITableView:  **UITableViewCellStyleDefault** and **UITableViewStyleGrouped**. Looks like the Default version shouldn't be displaying at all. Is it only happening in the simulator or on the device?

Comment: its happening on both simulator and device

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen when I used a UITableViewController in the storyboard and set its class to be my subclass of FormViewController.  I ended up removing it and using a UIViewController instead, placing a table view as a subview of the VC's view.

I think the problem is, if you use a UITableViewController it has some of its own assumptions and settings, and the FormViewController is creating its own, so you end up with two section headers at the same time.